# How can I keep only alphanumeric and numeric characters (codes), while deleting the rest of the string?

Tags: r, substring, character, gsub

I have a column full of text in which I have to extract only a fixed code which can be made only by numbers or by numbers and letters (like 23356978 and Z23489CDE or D123F598 and any other combination). 
How can I keep just those codes while removing the rest of the string?

I'm tryng something like

```
gsub("[A-F][A-Z]*[A-Z]","",string)
```

But like this I also lose the letters inside the codes

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can we see some examples of your strings?

Comment: Can we see some examples of your expected output?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/43294454/4137985

Comment: "CIG --- ZD5083D833",

Comment: Proposte di informazione e comunicazione - art. 78 del Reg. UE 508/2014 - PO FEAMP Sicilia 2014/2020 - DDG n. 21 del 30/01/2018 - DDG n. 538 del 26/09/2018 - Blue Sea Land 2018 - CIG ZD4251ACC6"

Comment: I only need to keep the code after "CIG"

Answer (score 2):

You can replace everything that isn't alpha-numeric with an empty string, like so:

```
a<-"aa-46,83!jhdf"
gsub("[^[:alnum:]]","",a)
[1] "aa4683jhdf"
```

Or, same thing:

```
gsub("\\W","",a)
```

(`\W` is the opposite of `\w`, which is the symbol for "word", or any alphanumeric character, although this will also keep underscores, which are part of \w, which you might not want)

Comment: `\W` is not equal to `[^[:alnum:]]`. At least it does not match `_` and `[^[:alnum:]]` [does](https://rextester.com/PSPV52535).

Comment: yes, I wrote as much in parentheses at the bottom. That's why it wasn't the main option.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```r
strings <- c("A5$^", "%Bhg*", "%HG458#")
gsub("[^[:alnum:]]", "", strings)
# [1] "A5"    "Bhg"   "HG458"
```

The `[:alnum:]` class matches all alphanumeric characters (upper- and lowercase letters and digits). The negation operator `^` inside of `[ ]` means to match everything *except* the patterns after it, so `[^[:alnum:]]` matches any *non*-alphanumeric character. The full `gsub` expression above then replaces any non-alphanumeric characters with the blank string `""`. See [`?regex`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html) for more details.

Comment: It doesnt' work it only removes che "spaces" among the words

Comment: Proposte di informazione e comunicazione - art. 78 del Reg. UE 508/2014 - PO FEAMP Sicilia 2014/2020 - DDG n. 21 del 30/01/2018 - DDG n. 538 del 26/09/2018 - Blue Sea Land 2018 - CIG ZD4251ACC6"

When I have something like this, I only need to keep the alpha-numeric code after the "CIG"

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `stringr` to replace all characters that are not alphanumeric:

```
x<-"aa-46,83!jhdf"
stringr::str_replace_all(x, "[^[:alnum:]]", "")
```

or directly extract them and paste into a string:

```
paste0(stringr::str_extract_all(x, "[:alnum:]")[[1]], collapse = "")
```

**Output**

```
"aa4683jhdf"
```